# Group by in subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need some help with group by in subquery. Can you help me to solve this grouping problem:

```
select
  DATEPART(wk, oh. ExportDate) as wk,
  DATEPART(dw,oh.ExportDate) as day,
  ro.Name,
  Pallets = sum(oh.Pallets),
  Box = (select count(Number) from OrderItem where ID_OrderHead = oh.Id) 
from
  OrderHeadPDAEvent ohpe
  left outer join OrderHead oh on oh.Id = ohpe.ID_OrderHeader
  left outer join Route ro on oh.ID_Route = ro.ID
where
  ID_Route = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    and
  oh.ExportDate > dbo.GetStartOfDay('2012-08-01 14:35:00.000' ) 
    and 
  oh.ExportDate < dbo.GetEndOfDay('2013-08-08 14:35:00.000')
group by 
  oh.ExportDate, ro.Name, oh.ID
order by 
  DATEPART(wk, oh. ExportDate)
```

And data looks like this:

```
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    5   49
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    2   45
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    2   38
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    1   26
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    1   64
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    2   45
26  3   Standard - Uten rute    3   64
```

I want to sum all rows to get them in 1 row only.

Comment: have you try with having clause instead of where ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      DATEPART(wk, oh.ExportDate) AS wk
    , DATEPART(dw, oh.ExportDate) AS day
    , ro.name
    , Pallets = SUM(oh.Pallets)
    , Box = SUM(n)
FROM dbo.OrderHeadPDAEvent ohpe
LEFT JOIN dbo.OrderHead oh ON oh.ID = ohpe.ID_OrderHeader
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Route] ro ON oh.ID_Route = ro.ID
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT n = COUNT(number), ID_OrderHead
     FROM dbo.OrderItem
     GROUP BY ID_OrderHead 
) t ON t.ID_OrderHead = oh.ID
WHERE ID_Route = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
     AND oh.ExportDate BETWEEN 
                         dbo.GetStartOfDay('2012-08-01 14:35:00.000') 
                         AND 
                         dbo.GetEndOfDay('2013-08-08 14:35:00.000')
GROUP BY
      oh.ExportDate
    , ro.name
ORDER BY wk
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 't.n' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Tryed to add t.n to last groupby but it did same like last one

Comment: @Endiss - if this solution fully suit you, please approve it.

Comment: Ye i had to w8 some time :)